# List of JAXB providers

Tags: jakarta-ee, jaxb

AFAIK, JAXB is just a specification (JSR222).
Java 1.6 has an implementation of it but it's also called as JAXB which is confusing to me. Because JPA also is a JSR specification but JPA providers have a name like EclipseLink, Hibernate and so on.

So, is there any list of JAXB providers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [Apache CXF](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-data-bindings.html) - bundled with [TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/apache-tomee.html)
- [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.19.1/index.html) - bundled with [Glassfish](https://glassfish.java.net/)
- [RESTEasy](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.1.GA/userguide/html/Built_in_JAXB_providers.html) - bundled with [Wildfly / JBoss](http://wildfly.org)
- [EclipseLink MOXy](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy)

There may be others that I'm not aware of.  All can be used outside of their parent JEE server too.

Comment: @stdunbar you seem to have listed JAX-RS providers rather than JAXB providers?

Comment: @Steve C - first link on the CXF link - JAXB support.  Section 4.2 of the Jersey link - Getting started with JAXB.  RESTEasy link is directly to JAXB providers.  Most JAXB implementations are bundled inside of JAX-RS because it is a dependency.

Comment: Actually I think we have both jumped on the `provider` keyword incorrectly. @RamazanPolat is asking about different implementations of the JSR222 JAXB specification (as EclipseLink and Hibernate are different implementations of the JPA specification).