# Jackson: jackson-dataformat-xml: Required attribute of JsonProperty annotation is ignored when deserializing from XML to Java

Tags: java, json, xml, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I have a problem using Jackson, more specific jackson-dataformat-xml.

When JSON is parsed, there is a check on properties that are annotated with JsonProperty with attibute required to true.
If the required property is missing, a MismatchedInputException with message "Missing required creator property" is thrown.

When XML is parsed, there is no check on required properties/element. If the required property/element is missing, there is no exception.
Adding DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_MISSING_CREATOR_PROPERTIES doesn't make any difference.

There is constructor is annotated with JsonCreator and with the required property annotated with JsonProperty.

It worked when jackson-dataformat-xml version 2.11.4 was used, it doesn't work since version 2.12.0

Do I need to use another annotation for a required XML element?

Example class:

```
@JsonRootName(value = "bar")
public class Bar
{
    @JsonProperty(value = "foo", required = true)
    private int foo;

    public Bar()
    {}

    @JsonCreator
    public Bar(@JsonProperty(value = "foo", required = true) final int foo)
    {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public int getFoo()
    {
        return this.foo;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return Objects.hash(this.foo);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj)
    {
        if (this == obj)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof Bar))
        {
            return false;
        }
        final Bar other = (Bar) obj;
        return this.foo == other.foo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Bar: " + Objects.toString(this.foo);
    }
}
```

Example of unit test on JSON, this unit test throws an exception as expected, because property foo is missing.

```
    @Test(expected = JsonProcessingException.class)
    public void deserializeJson() throws Exception
    {
        final ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        final Bar expected = new Bar(123);
        final Bar actual = jsonMapper.readValue("{}", Bar.class); // missing property foo in JSON string
    }
```

Example of unit test on XML, this unit test does not throw an exception

```
  @Test(expected = JsonProcessingException.class)
   public void deserializeXml() throws Exception
   {
       final XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
       xmlMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_MISSING_CREATOR_PROPERTIES, true);

       final Bar expected = new Bar(123);
       final Bar actual = xmlMapper.readValue("<bar></bar>", Bar.class); // missing element foo in XML string

       Assert.fail("Expected com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Missing required creator property 'foo' (index 0)");
   }
```

Comment: Refer: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml Jackson XML bind is not intended to be full JAXB compliant. The behavious you are observing is due to that. One suggestion would be to use JAXB annotations on your POJO classes and use a JAXB provider (refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41249432/list-of-jaxb-providers) and check.